# MYSQL Composite Key for "FriendList"

Tags: mysql, composite-primary-key

I have a table where I'm storing "Friend" associations. So column 1 is userID and column2 is friendID (where friendID is just another userID from the users table.

I've been planning to have two entries per relationship. To explain, let's say user 100 wants to be friends with 200. My table would look like this:

```
USERID = 100
FRIENDID = 200
STATUS = 'friend'
```

But then also

```
USERID = 200
FRIENDID = 100
STATUS = 'friend'
```

After they accept the friend request. The idea is that the relationship is defined in both directions so I can set different status depending on whether they're "requesting friendship" or if the users want to categorize or put custom notes on the friends.

I wanted to use the userID and FriendID columns as a composite key, but will MYSQL die in a fire if I have the same combination of userID and FriendID in two places (even though they're reversed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have FriendID and UserID as a composite key. This will mean that you can't have 2 different statuses for the same friendship. Why would MySQL crash?

Comment: if I have one row with userID 100 and friendID 200 does MYSQL treat that as different than userID 200 and friendID 100? And what if both have the status of "friend"? The values between the two rows are the same, but in different order. I haven't been able to determine what Mysql would do in this instance.

Comment: I tested it an it seems to be working. I guess I was worried over nothing. As long as the keys don't occur in the same order with the same values it doesn't complain. You did say something about it not liking the same value for status though... I tried setting it the same manually in PHPadmin and it didn't seem to care so I'm not sure what you meant, but it's working so thanks!

Comment: It means if you try to add 2 rows with the same userID and same friendID, the second one will fail, unless you have a "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" clause in your INSERT query.